# How to update some collection with different query parameters and with different set values?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an array of mongoDB collection -

```js
 [

    {
      "_id": "630499244683ed43d56edd06",
      "userId": "630499234683ed43d56edd05",
      "isPaid": "true"
    },
  
    {
      "_id": "6304c19bda84477b41b4bbfa",
      "userId": "630499234683ed43d56edd05",
      "isPaid": "true"
    },
  
    {
      "_id": "6304c1b5da84477b41b4bbfb",
      "userId": "630499234683ed43d56edd05",
      "isPaid": "true"
    },
    {
      "_id": "6304c1cbda84477b41b4bbfc",
      "userId": "630499234683ed43d56edd05",
      "isPaid": "true"
    },
]
```

I just want to add the `order` property to all the object but for all the specific `_id` I need to add the different `order value`

Like this -

```js
 [

    {
      "_id": "630499244683ed43d56edd06",
      "userId": "630499234683ed43d56edd05",
      "isPaid": "true",
      "order": 7
    },
  
    {
      "_id": "6304c19bda84477b41b4bbfa",
      "userId": "630499234683ed43d56edd05",
      "isPaid": "true",
      "order": 5
    },
  
    {
      "_id": "6304c1b5da84477b41b4bbfb",
      "userId": "630499234683ed43d56edd05",
      "isPaid": "true",
      "order": 0,
    },
    {
      "_id": "6304c1cbda84477b41b4bbfc",
      "userId": "630499234683ed43d56edd05",
      "isPaid": "true",
      "order": 2
    },
]
```

Please let me know How do I implement this approach in mongoDB?
I'm not using mongoose in my project.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the structure of the coming data, how it grouped with _id and the count of order. If it is an array of object, you can use loop. I don't think there is a solution to update different values in only one code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want specific `ids` to have specific `order` values you need to update them separately. You could use `bulkWrite` with the `updateOne` method.

```js
   db.collection.bulkWrite( [
      { updateOne: {
         filter: { _id: ... },
         update: { $set: { order: 1 } }
      } },
      ...
   ] )
```

Refer to the MongoDB documentation and to your language driver in particular: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#updateone-and-updatemany